# Xamarin - Visual Studio 2015 - Pages

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

I'm new to making mobile Apps and I've recently developed a prototype App, and noticed I've used a lot of pages... On Xamarin - Visual Studio 2015 I know there is a way to 'bypass' this problem, and instead of adding loads of different XAML pages, you can just change the contents? BUT how to do that i have no idea? if anyone knows how to do it, any help would be appreciated!!

**What I think... maybe :S :**

If I click a button which would normally change page, instead of creating another XAML page, could I just 'delete' all contents and 'load' different contents onto the same page? would that work or is there a better way?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Yes, that could work, but generally you would want to create a page for each page in your app.  I'm not sure why you think doing this is a problem.

Comment: thanks for the reply! but wouldn't it be less efficient? like wouldn't it effect the speed of the App having 10+ pages ?